# D3 Sunburst. How to set different ring\level widths

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Help! I've been searching for ages and not found anything about this. I basically want to be able to set the size (%, pixel, relative.. i don't mind) of each layer in a D3 sunburst. That could be done either in the data or in the code based on number or parents I guess?  I have a sunburst and want the inner rings to take up most of the space with the outer ring just a thin layer on the outside. This is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TimBrighton/rh02t94h/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Dimensions of sunburst.
var width = 550;
var height = 550;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// make `colors` an ordinal scale
var colors = d3.scale.category20();

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0; 

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, 100])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return radius * (d.y) / 100; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return radius * (d.y + d.dy) / 100; });

var json = getData();
createVisualization(json);

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

    // Basic setup of page elements.
    initializeBreadcrumbTrail();

    d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

    // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
    // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
    vis.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", radius)
        .style("opacity", 0);

    // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
    var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
        .filter(function(d) {
            return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
        });

    var uniqueNames = (function(a) {
        var output = [];
        a.forEach(function(d) {
            if (output.indexOf(d.name) === -1) {
                output.push(d.name);
            }
        });
        return output;
    })(nodes);

    // set domain of colors scale based on data
    colors.domain(uniqueNames);

    // make sure this is done after setting the domain
    drawLegend();

    var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
        .data(nodes)
       .enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.name); })
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover);

    // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
    d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

    // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
    totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
};

// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {

  var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
  var percentageString = percentage + "%";
  if (percentage < 0.1) {
    percentageString = "< 0.1%";
  }

  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(percentageString);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.name); });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", colors.domain().length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(colors.domain())
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d); });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
}

function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}

// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how 
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
};

function getData() {
    return {
 "name": "ref",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "june11",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "atts",
         "children": [
          {"name": "early", "size": 11},
          {"name": "jcp", "size": 40},
          {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 50},
          {"name": "stillon", "size": 195},
          {"name": "jo",

             "children": [
              {"name": "early",  "size": 100},
              {"name": "jcp", "size": 67},
              {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 110},
                 {"name": "stillon", "size": 154},

               {"name": "sus1",      
                "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 11},
                    {"name": "jcp", "size": 118},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 39},
                      {"name": "stillon", "size": 2779}
                  ]
                },

               {"name": "sus5",
                 "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 0},
                  {"name": "jcp", "size": 64},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 410},
                     {"name": "stillon", "size": 82}
                  ]
                },

               {"name": "sus9",
                 "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 1018},
                  {"name": "jcp", "size": 3458},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 106},
                     {"name": "stillon", "size": 243}
                  ]
                },

               {"name": "sus13",
                 "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 110},
                  {"name": "jcp", "size": 190},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 80},
                     {"name": "stillon", "size": 9190},
                     {"name": "allsus", "size": 3970}
                     ]
                    }

                 ]
              }
         ]
        },

      {"name": "noatt", "size": 30}
    ]
    }

 ]
};
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *polylinear* scale that reduces the upper reaches of a domain to a smaller portion of the output range - this blog from 2011 actually points out the ability to do this clearer than the official documentation - http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/

e.g. d3.scale.linear().domain([0,0.8,1.0]).range([0,0.98,1.0]);

Then apply that scale to your d.y and d.dy calculations as below -

0 to 0.8 will map to 0 to 0.98 of the range, leaving the last depth to map to just 2% of the radius on screen. This of course works as you have six rings, other numbers will need different cutoffs but in that case it's just looping through and finding the max of d.y.

```
 var rscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,0.8,1.0]).range([0,0.98,1.0]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return radius * rscale(d.y/100); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return radius * rscale((d.y + d.dy)/100); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rh02t94h/3/

Comment: That is great, thank you! Works perfectly on this jsfilddle as we can see :-). Now just need to translate to other code :-)

Answer (score 1):

To set custom widths and radius for each level of a sunburst, I hardcoded the inner and outer widths in this way

```
    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, (radius * radius) +50])
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });
    var inner = {1: 300,2:360, 3:420, 4:480,5:540,6:600,7:660,8:720};
    var outer = {1: 350,2:410,3:470, 4:530,5:590,6:650,7:710,8:770};

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return inner[d.depth];})
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return outer[d.depth] });
```